# For loops and nested lists issue

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a set of nested list being returned via the `JSON.Loads` method from a website XHR request:

```
[[[13, u'Arsenal', [[[[0, 1], [1, 18], [7, 1], [8, 1], [[[u'fk_foul_lost', [82]], 
[u'total_red_card', [0]], [u'total_yel_card', [21]]]]]]]], 
    ...
    ...
    ...
[184, u'Burnley', [[[[1, 11], [9, 1], [[[u'fk_foul_lost', [78]], [u'total_red_card', [0]], 
[u'total_yel_card', [12]]]]]]]], [259, u'Swansea', [[[[0, 3], [1, 14], [[[u'fk_foul_lost', [99]], 
[u'total_red_card', [2]], [u'total_yel_card', [13]]]]]]]]]]
```

Where the above nested list is allocated to the variable `responser`I am using the following code:

```
for match in responser: 
    for num_events, team, events in match:

        for y in events[0]:
            for sub in y:
            print sub
```

This returns a result like this:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 18]
[7, 1]
[8, 1]
[[[u'fk_foul_lost', [82]], [u'total_red_card', [0]], [u'total_yel_card', [21]]]]
...
...
...
[1, 11]
[9, 1]
[[[u'fk_foul_lost', [78]], [u'total_red_card', [0]], [u'total_yel_card', [12]]]]
[0, 3]
[1, 14]
[[[u'fk_foul_lost', [99]], [u'total_red_card', [2]], [u'total_yel_card', [13]]]]
```

However what I want is just the numeric values within:

```
[[[u'fk_foul_lost', [99]], [u'total_red_card', [2]], [u'total_yel_card', [13]]]]
```

Can anyone tell me the syntax I need to finish this code off?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for match in responser: 
    for num_events, team, events in match:

        for y in events[0]:
            for sub in y:
                if isinstance(sub[0], list):
                    print sub
```

Comment: @friedi...hi, thanks for replying...yes this did what i wanted. can you talk me though what the code is doing though please?

Comment: The only thing I added was the line `if isinstance(sub[0], list):`. Here I check if the first element in the row is an array/list.